# MySQL: BETWEEN vs MONTH. Which faster?

Tags: mysql

What the best/fast practice for getting month records from MySQL db?

Before, for get current month records I use:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM `mytable` 
WHERE `date` BETWEEN CAST(DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-01') as DATE) AND LAST_DAY(NOW());
```

But find next solution:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM `mytable` 
WHERE MONTH(calldate) = MONTH(CURDATE()) AND YEAR(calldate) = YEAR(CURDATE());
```

In my real base, both request get almost same time (), but this "almost" worried me. In base about 25 million records. `date` column indexed.
Can anyone give advice?

Comment: which one was faster and by how much? How many records did it cycle through? I believe that the `BETWEEN` keyword would be better suited simply because that is what its designed to do.

Comment: Clause like `WHERE MONTH(calldate) =` will never use index even if the column is indexed, so better use between as you have now. You dont see the diff now may be you do not have large data, but having large data will definitely show you the difference.

Comment: Thanks @AbhikChakraborty, you send me in right direction. MONTH function indeed [not use index](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?115,86654,86654#msg-86654) and this the key point for me.